# When is ammonia and water a strong ligand?

Tags: coordination-compounds

While studying the spectrochemical series, my sir said that as ammonia and water lie in the center, their behaviour as a ligand is tough to judge. For example if we have CO as a ligand, we know that the electrons of the central atom tend to pair up, but he said that the same cannot be predicted for water and ammonia. Is this true, or is there some logic which will help to predict whether the electrons pair up or not. For example in [Co(NH)6]+3, the electrons pair up and the hybridization is d2sp3. But such pairing up is not seen at times in other compounds.

Comment: You should not be so concerned with whether the ligand is strong- or weak-field. That is only half of the story. After all, you are looking at a *metal-ligand complex* which can be *high-spin* or *low-spin*. Although the ligand plays an important part in determining that, the metal is equally important. See: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/59171/16683

Comment: Also, "hybridisation is d2sp3" - please note that the use of hybridisation for transition metal complexes is an outdated and inconsistent theory: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/76726/16683